# regex to match set of permutations

Tags: regex

I want to flag match for a string under various permutations orders satisfying these criterion

1) Both alphabets 's','t' should occur once and only once

2) Alphabets  'n','o','p' either of them can occur zero or one time

Is there a regex that can suit this purpose?

Comment: Do you mean letters instead of alphabets?

Comment: I hesitate to submit a meta proposal to forbid the addition of questions with only the regex tag.

Comment: Lookaheads might be helpful here: http://www.regular-expressions.info/lookaround.html.

Comment: which language are you using

Comment: @dystroy that was a very formal language..;)

Comment: Do you have access to look around or only the basic regex constructs? Because this sincerely looks like an homework

Answer (score 0):

You can use this regex

```
 ^(?=[^s]*s[^s]*$)(?=[^t]*t[^t]*$)(?=[^n]*n?[^n]*$)(?=[^o]*o?[^o]*$)(?=[^p]*p?[^p]*$).*$
  ----------------                -----------------                
         |                                 |->matches further only if there is 0 or 1 occurance of n
         |
         |->matches further only if there is a single occurance of s
```

Use `singleline` or `dotall` option with the regex

Comment: I don't think you need the `.*$` at the end.

Comment: @FelixKling yes indeed..you are right..it's not necessary if he wants to only check for match..

Comment: I don't find this to work with grep.

echo "nsot" |grep ' ^(?=[^s]*s[^s]*$)(?=[^t]*t[^t]*$)(?=[^n]*n?[^n]*$)(?=[^o]*o?[^o]*$)(?=[^p]*p?[^p]*$).*$'

this doesn't give a match. What am I missing here?

Comment: @Shankar you have to use the **s** [modifier](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlre.html#Modifiers) with the regex